# How configure Apache HTTP so URL will work without context for three Tomcat 7 Java apps

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have a Windows environment running a Java app on three different Tomcat 7.0.39 application servers, each with a context root of a different name, behind a single Apache HTTP 2.2.22 using mod_jk.  There are three sites with distinct domain names but users must access the sites with URL/context (domainname1.com/context1, domainname2.com/context2, domainname3.com/context3).  VirtualHosts are configured in httpd-ssl.conf.  Currently httpd.conf specifies:

```
JkMount /context1/* worker1
JkMount /context2/* worker2
JkMount /context3/* worker3

JkMountCopy All
```

Is there a configuration that will allow users to go to URL with no context specified?  I tried making the Tomcat webapp ROOT but that didn’t work to serve all three sites.  Also had no success with mod_rewrite or mod_proxy.  I do see that others have asked a similar question but found no answer specific to my environment.  Is this possible?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Name your web applications `context1`, `context2`, and `context3` in each Tomcat instance and change your `httpd.conf` mappings to these:

```
JkMount /context1|/* worker1
JkMount /context2|/* worker2
JkMount /context3|/* worker3
```

If you want users to be able to go to `/` instead of `/context1` then you are going to have to use different `VirtualHost`s on Apache httpd and configure each webapp to be the `ROOT` webapp on each Tomcat instance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay in responding.  I will give this a try and report back.